# Looping DIV block after it has been filled with 3 items with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I have the following raw HTML code:

```
<section class="cols services-modern">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span4">
                <i class="content"></i>
                <h3>Title</h3>
                <p>Blah.....</p>
            </div>
            <div class="span4">
                <i class="content"></i>
                <h3>Title</h3>
                <p>Blah.....</p>
            </div>
            <div class="span4">
                <i class="content"></i>
                <h3>Title</h3>
                <p>Blah.....</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Which i would like to loop after the div has been filled with 3 contents.
So far i have done the following with no luck..

```
<?php for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($content); $i++) : ?>
<section class="cols services-modern">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row-fluid">
<?php if($i % 3 == 0): ?>
    <div class="span4">
        <i class="content"></i>
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <?= htmlspecialchars_decode($blah); ?>
    </div>
<?php else: ?>
    <div class="span4">
        <i class="content"></i>
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <?= htmlspecialchars_decode($blah); ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
</div>
</section>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

Could anyone help me to spot my mistake, thanks.

Comment: well, your `true` clause html is identical to your `false` clause, so the whole if() is rather pointless... By "loop" you probably mean "make a new row"? If that's the case, then your `span4` chunk stays constant, and your if() checks handle the `row-fluid` and/or `container` html instead. When you hit 3 divs output, you put out the "wrappers", which starts a new row.

Comment: @MarcB Yeah i actually noticed that. It just that i have been experimenting with the if clause, with no luck. It just happened that i pasted this identical clause here.

Answer (score 0):

This is what u expecting?

```
<section class="cols services-modern">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row-fluid">
    <?php for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($content); $i++) : if($i % 3 == 0): ?>
      <div class="span4"> <i class="content"></i>
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <?= htmlspecialchars_decode($blah); ?>
      </div>
      <?php else: ?>
      <div class="span4"> <i class="content"></i>
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <?= htmlspecialchars_decode($blah); ?>
      </div>
      <?php endif; endfor; ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: hi not really, since the section, container class and row fluid is outside the loops. I need it to be repeated every modulo 3.

Answer (score 0):

try this one..

```
<?php for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($content); $i++) : if($i % 3 == 0): ?>
<section class="cols services-modern">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row-fluid">

      <div class="span4"> <i class="content"></i>
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <?= htmlspecialchars_decode($blah); ?>
      </div>
      <?php else: ?>
      <div class="span4"> <i class="content"></i>
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <?= htmlspecialchars_decode($blah); ?>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<?php endif; endfor; ?>
```

Comment: hi Mani, thanks for the suggestion. However every modulo 3 is printed without the section tag.

Comment: did you need div block only  when modulo 3?

Comment: yes, basically i would like to imitate a table with 3 columns only using CSS.